# Save series chart type for later use

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

This may be more of a scope question than a HighCharts question.

I have a function that changes the chart type, please see below:

```
function ChangeChartType(chart, newType) {
    newType = newType.toLowerCase();
    var numberofseries = chart.series.length;
    var i = 0;
    if (newType == 'reset') {
        for (i; i < numberofseries; i++) {
            if (typeof chart.series[i].defaulttype == 'string') {
                chart.series[i].update({
                    type: chart.series[i].defaulttype
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (i; i < numberofseries; i++) {
            if (typeof chart.series[i].defaulttype != 'string') {
                chart.series[i].defaulttype = chart.series[i].type; //The new property does not survive
            }
            chart.series[i].update({
                type: newType
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a new property on the series objects named "defaulttype" in order to save the chart type that was set when the chart was created. When a "Reset" button is clicked I want to change the chart type back to what is stored in the property.

The problem is the new property disappears outside of the function. What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

I created a fiddle to demonstrate the entire issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/xeRRS/9/

Comment: I updated the Fiddle to show that each series can have a different chart type that must be stored when the 'Reset' button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also setup a default type in the chart object, then in your custom function refer to the Highcharts.charts[0] object (keeping your chart), extracting default serie from userOptions.

```
Highcharts.charts[0].userOptions.chart.defaultType
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xeRRS/8/

Comment: Thanks but it does not appear that your suggestion saves the chart type for each chart series, which is needed because every series could have a different value.  On 'reset', it looks like you are just setting the chart type to the single value that is stored at the chart level.

Comment: So each serie should keep type during load, which can be extracted when you click reset, right?

Comment: I just updated the Fiddle to show a chart configuration where each series has a different chart type. I wasn't planning to store the chart type on load, just whenever one of the 'non-Reset' buttons are clicked.

Comment: Ok, so I updated my example, by adding a callback which set default parameter and use it in reset, hope that is correct with your expectaitons. http://jsfiddle.net/xeRRS/10/

Comment: I see what you are suggesting with the callback, nice! But I also wanted to avoid modifying our code that generates the chart configuration.  I was hoping to contain all of the logic within the ChangeChartType function.

Comment: You can add callback by Highcharts api, avoding core modification. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: I think writing a plugin to add a startType series property is beyond my abilities. I do not see how to bring together your example with the API documentation.

Comment: I did manage to get a little further on Sebastian's plugin idea. I managed to get the plugin to create the startType property for each series but it is still coming up undefined within the ChangeChartType function. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usq62/1/

Comment: I seem to have hit a roadblock. How should the plugin be written to implement the callback that Sebastian suggested?

Comment: I mean remove callback and use construction, desribed in part: "HOOKING UP TO CHART.INIT"

Comment: It looks like I finally got this working. Thanks! This is pretty much the same approach I was originally trying to take so I am not sure why the callback works and setting the value within the ChangeChartType function does not but at this point I can't spend any more time on this. Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usq62/2/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, a simple way to achieve your objective is to store the "defaultType" (camel casing helps see in the desert) property against the chart variable as it looks like the series array is overwritten somewhere inside the library. Here is the working version of your code http://jsfiddle.net/4ecHP/

On a different note, adding a property to an object where it is not clear on what is happening inside that object is a bit dangerous (the chart object may have a defaultType property already), instead you can store the defaultType as a global variable or create a _settings object in the window object and store all your chart settings there like

```
_settings={
        height: 500,
        spacingLeft: -35,
        spacingRight: 12,
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        defaultType: null
}
```

In this case, on reset you can call chart.series[i].update({type: _settings.defaultType});

Comment: Thanks but it does not appear that your suggestion saves the chart type for each chart series, which is needed because every series could have a different value. On 'reset', it looks like you are just setting the chart type to the single value that is stored at the chart level.

Comment: I didn't investigate the HighCharts library to determine whether it overwrites properties but if that is happening then I guess the only thing I can do is something like your suggestion to save the chart types in a different location. I wanted to avoid that.